# Why is my meta analysis OR and 95% CI less precise than my study results?

Tags: r, logistic, meta-analysis, odds-ratio

I am trying to perform a simple weighted average meta analysis of 2 odds ratios from 2 studies (I will be adding more studies when I get the results). However, when I meta analyse using the METAFOR package in R, my combined result is far less precise than both of the actual studies which doesn't make sense to me. Can someone shed some light? The image shows the study results and the output result of the random effects meta analysis (this result doesn't change if I use fixed effects).

[image: Individual study result and meta analysis result]

Comment: Please provide fully reproducible code. I suspect you are passing your SEs to `rma()` as the second argument, but that's for passing variances.

Comment: And please show the actual output not truncated. Clearly the se are not equal as you post since the width of the ci differ. Also confirm as your tag suggests that you are analysing on the log odds scale as the tag suggests and not the odds scale as your post suggests.

Comment: You might also want to change the units.